# Elastic Kibana Dashboard Visualisation. How to display time since last response from an API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I'm trying to create a dashboard in Kibana that shows the last time an API logged a response to Elastic and then I would like to colour them green, amber or red based on how long ago the last response for each API was. However I can't figure out how.

I have tried using the aggregations visualisations within the Dashboard tool and I can get it to display the last response time for each API but I can't get it to change colour based on how long ago it was. I have seen that you can group by filters and use them to get the last api response within each timeframe that I wan't but you can't colour based on filters?